# Why D1 is assumed to be reverse-biased and D2 forward-biased in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

In the solution of this problem, in order to calculate the value of 'v', D1 is considered to be reversed-biased and D2 forward-biased.

How do we know that beforehand?

[image]

A constant voltage drop model is used, with Vf =  0.7 V.

Comment: D2 will drop ~0.7V when current flows trough it trough the 2K to the -3V rail. Thus it's cathode will be at ~2.3V. D1 then also has 2.3V on it's cathode but only 1V on it's anode, reverse biassing it.

Comment: The "strongest" wins? (in this simple case).

Comment: You just have to assume for both diodes (one is forward, another is reverse for eg ) and solve the node voltage, check if the assumption for both diodes still hold even after solving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *How do we know that beforehand?*

We look at each diode in turn and forget that the other one is present in the circuit. In other words we test scenarios like this: -

**Ignoring D1**

Because there is +3 volts on the anode of D2 and, because the cathode connects to a negative supply voltage via a resistor, we can say that the cathode of D2 will be about 0.7 volts lower than the anode hence, the cathode voltage will be about +2.3 volts.

**Ignoring D2**

By inspection, we don't need to consider the scenario of ignoring D2 because we should recognize that D2's cathode voltage (from above) naturally forces D1's cathode to be at a higher voltage than its anode hence, D1 must be reverse biased.

---

OK, say I chose to ignore D2 first: -

**Ignoring D2**

The cathode voltage will be 0.3 volts (as per the method above)

**Ignoring D1**

The cathode voltage will be 2.3 volts (as per the method above)

**LOGIC ANALYSIS**

If when both diodes are present the common cathode voltage is 0.3 volts then there has to be a gazillion amps through D3 **OR** the common cathode voltage rises to 2.3 volts. This D2 is on and D1 is off.

Comment: Is there a more general way to find this out? Because this way, if I had ignored D2 at first, then I would have arrived at a conclusion that D1 will be forward biased.

Comment: This method works because if you had ignored D2 first, then the voltage at D1's cathode would be 0.3 volts and, that will clearly forward bias D2 - you test scenarios and use logic. There is no general way of finding this other than a process of elimination.

Comment: I'm still very confused. It'd be very nice of you, if you could explain the scenario in which D2 is ignored first. How do you know D1 will be reverse biased in that case? Doesn't considering D1's cathode will be 0.3 volts, imply that it is forward biased.

Comment: @theCursedPirate I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. One final question: what about the scenario in which both the '0.3V' and '2.3V' add up i.e. both the diodes are forward biased (or the cases where they substract). Shouldn't those also be a case we should consider? Or, are v=0.3V or 2.3V are the only possible outcomes?

Comment: @theCursedPirate both diodes cannot be forward biased in the above problem. For them to be both forward biased, they would have to have the same anode voltage.

Comment: To the OP, if you assume D1 is forward biased you will pretty quickly realize that the forward voltage on D2 is ridiculously large (> 0.7, so impossible using your simple model), and would result in D2 conducting many, many amps (maybe hundreds or thousands of amps according to the diode equation). So that is your reality check. Then you say OK, what if we assume D2 is forward biased by 0.7V rule and then you will see that D1 is reversed biased and everything is consistent and sane.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what sort of model of a diode you're using. But ultimately, it's because 3>1.

If they are ideal diodes, then the forward voltage across them is 0V. In which case, D2 is forward biased, v is 3V and D1 has -2V across it.

If Vf is 0.7V, then v will be (3 - 0.7) = 2.3V, making the voltage across D1 as -1.3V.

If you're using something like a model of a real silicon diode, then the voltages may be slightly different.

The assumption only fails if you have some weird diode with a forward voltage >2V.

Comment: *"The assumption only fails if you have some weird diode with a forward voltage >2V"* Worth noting in your answer for beginner OPs that Vf>2V isn't weird at all as many LEDs and opto-LEDs have that. Not gonna be those in this circuit, etc etc, but I wouldn't put 'weird' in their heads. Otherwise a good and concise answer, if modified as above will upvote and delete this comment.

Comment: The text asks to use constant voltage drop model (diode voltage=0.7V). But, thanks for the explanation of scenarios where that isn't the case.

Comment: @theCursedPirate, not in the posted question it doesn't, and that's what we're answering :-) Please edit your question so it contains all the information. Remember, you're posting for future OPs to learn from and they may know little about electronics. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are visually oriented (and after all, that's why we draw schematics), we can rearrange some things to make this easier to analyze.

First of all, we can swap the two diodes together with their voltage sources, since they connect to the same place.  Then we'll "bend" D1 down and D2 up.  We get figure "A".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzKemP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In figure "B", we realize that voltage is just the potential difference between any two chosen points.  This circuit's reference, or "ground", isn't even pictured.  No matter; I will take my voltmeter's negative lead and stick it on D1's anode lead.  That point becomes the zero reference, and I subtract 1 from all the other voltages. The voltage difference between any two points shown, has not changed!
If I really care about the answer, I can add 1v back to whatever *v* turns out to be, after I come up with an answer.

Now we see that D2's anode is the most positive part and so current will flow through it.  The other side of D2 almost the same (0.7 volts less) which is still positive as far as D1 is concerned.  So D1 is reverse biased and isn't going to conduct.  Unless something can drag D1's cathode down below 0v.... That -4v through 2k ohms?  Not likely.

The voltage of voltage sources can't be altered, and the resistance represented by the diode is, well, in an ideal world, zero, and in the real world, something like 4 ohms.  2k doesn't stand a chance in a fight like that.

As long as we've come this far, we may as well look at the resistor. Knowing there is 1.3 volts on one end, and -4 volts on the other, we can divide that 5.3 volt difference by 2k and come up with the current (2.65 mA).  Oh, and I said I could get the voltage at *v*, which is just the 1.3v, then adding back the 1v I took away in the beginning, gives 2.3 volts *in the original circuit*.

If you want to be a purist, you can take the 4 ohms represented by the diode, make a voltage divider with 4 ohms on top and 2k on the bottom.  Your answer then changes by (2000/2004) and that change is going to be less than the difference between the "0.7v" for the diode, and the *actual diode drop* which would then have to take into account temperature, current, and so on.  We are close enough with our results.